# TeamCity 9.1.1 upgrade not working

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm currently using TeamCity 9.0 with MS-SQL as the repository. I want to upgrade to version 9.1.1. I run the installer and I see 9.0 being uninstalled, followed by the 9.1.1 installation. After the installation is done TeamCity won't come back. The Web portal shows this error:

```
TeamCity server is connecting to MSSQL database. The database server is not started yet, or the database specified in '/config/database.properties' file is inaccessible.
```

I am using the same user account as the previous installation so it doesn't look like a permissions issue.

According to the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Upgrade) the installer should prompt for the data directory, but I never got that prompt.

While uninstalling I removed the TeamCity/lib/jdbc folder (those are the libraries to use MS-SQL). After installing 9.1.1 I copied back the folder and restarted the TC service.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check your config/database.properties file, and see if your database is still there.

Comment: Where is that file located at? Normally I could access the Data Directory from TemCity's UI (which is not working right now). I can check the file system on the TC server directly. Where can I find the database.properties file?

Comment: Go to Administration -> Global Settings and you will see Data Directory property on that page with a Browse link next to it. Browse and you will see the database.properties file in config subfolder.
If you cannot find it through the TC UI, just go ahead and search in the installation folder for a file named "database.properties"

Comment: The TC UI only shows a message:    TeamCity server is connecting to MSSQL database. The database server is not started yet, or the database specified in '/config/database.properties' file is inaccessible. The connection string is ok in the database.properties file.